# Why can't you use constexpr on variables declared but not defined in a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I was reading through C++ Primer 5th Edition, and was confused as to why it's possible to use a constexpr pointer on variables **defined** outside of a function but not **declared** outside a function.

Is there any times when you would define outside of a function? It seems you often will declare outside of functions when using extern, but I'm not sure how often one would define variables outside a function (unless main doesn't count as a function in this case).

**EDIT**: Emphasis mine

> For reasons we'll cover... variables defined inside a function are not stored at a fixed address. Hence, we cannot use a constexpr point to such variables. On the other hand, the address of an object **defined** outside of any function is a constant expression and so may be used to initialize a constexpr pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure what the book says, but `extern int i; constexpr int* p = &i;` (at namespace scope) is perfectly valid AFAIK. Can you post an exact quote (preferably with some sample code)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're on 2.4.4 "constexpr and constant expressions". Is `i and j must be defined outside any function` the comment you're referring to?

Comment: There is no sample code for that section, but I'll add the exact text

Comment: @remyabel That's the section I'm on. I'm confused about why it has to be defined rather than merely declared.

Comment: It's an attempt at simplification. A variable declared outside of any function will necessarily be defined outside any function as well (if it is defined at all). The book isn't trying to draw a distinction between defined/declared; it's trying to draw a distinction between defined in a function and defined outside one.

Comment: ^^ Exactly what T.C. said. You're getting hung up on the distinction between declared and defined, when it's trying to explain a difference between inside a function and outside a function

Comment: Thanks T.C. and Jonathan.